# Angular 2 - How do I get navigated from url in canactivate gaurd

Tags: url, angular, typescript

I have page1 and page2. I added canActivate gaurd on page2 route and want to know in the if I came from page1? How do I do that?

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    //If from Page 1 { clearCache() }
    return true;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

I was trying to find the answer to this question as well, and finally found it. In the constructor for your guard class, you need (private router: Router); then in your canActivate guard, you can use this.router.url to check the URL you are coming from:

```
export class StatusGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        console.log(`route ${route.url}`); // the url you are going to
        console.log(`state ${state.url}`); // the url you are going to
        console.log(`router ${this.router.url}`); // the url you are coming from
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its important to be aware that `route.url` is a `UrlSegment[]` type with the next path and the `state.url` is a string with query params and everything.

Answer (score 9):

First doit like this: it will give you a URL:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
      console.log(state.url);
}
```

if you want to redirect user to from which url he/she came from you can do it like this: for information read [official tutorial docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) under **TEACH AUTHGUARD TO AUTHENTICATE** section.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;

        return this.checkLogin(url);
      }

      checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

        // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
        this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

        // Navigate to the login page with extras
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't want to redirect to login or some page. I want to clear cache when user navigates from page1 to this page 2 and I want to retain cache when navigated from other pages to this page.

Comment: When canActivate gets executed, the page url is still the previous page. so I was able to get the url by window.location.href. But want to see if there is Angular way of doing this.

Comment: state.url will give pervious url.u want current url user ActivatedrouteSnapshot "snapshot" property.